# Hybrid database synchronization without data sync agent

Tags: multi-tenant, data-synchronization

I'm working on a project to create hybrid SQL database per tenant model. While we were able to replicate the on-premise databases to databases in Azure. I'm not able to find a way to continuously sync both on-prem DB and cloud DB (We cannot use data sync agent or transaction replication). We are looking for any other alternatives that we can try to achieve our purpose.

Also, how does synchronization works when the internet is down and cannot sync with cloud?

Sorry for my ignorance since I'm new to this field.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, can you add some details and tools used?

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use data sync agent? It can be installed in other machine that has access to the database and internet.

Comment: we are looking for a sync frequency of 1-2 minutes, while Azure data sync agent requires the frequency to be set 5 minutes (minimum)